# Restricting New User "Assigned User Group" Options for Manager Level Accounts

Tags: joomla-4.x, template-override, joomla-user-groups, com-users

I've created a new user group under the "Manager" ACL called "User Manager". The only function of the "User Manager" is to create or delete "Registered" user accounts. How do I restrict that "User Manager" ACL in such a way that when they create a new user account, the only ACL that they can assign that new user to is the "Registered" ACL? By default the "Manager" ACL (and it's subclasses) can create a new user and also assign them to the "Manager" ACL, or others like "Author", "Editor", etc. I need to restrict new user creation to only "Registered" users.

[image: User Manager]

Comment: I suspect that you may not be able to do this with configuration. I think that you'd have to write a plugin that gets triggered on the onUserBeforeSave event described at https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserBeforeSave. But someone else might still come through with a config solution ...